# CSS Height : Unable to increase the height of parent class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

An interesting problem in front of me. I have

```
<div class="box-content">
    <p style="height: inherit; width: inherit;">
        <iframe width="100%" height=" 100%" src="http://localhost/imagebase/image/data/banner/swf/Comp1.swf"></iframe>
    </p>
</div>
```

I need to make this code mobile compatible as well. What I am seeing that if I fix the size of `p` then it takes same on mobile as we all know. but in case of `inherit` it takes the width of its parent div, which is mobile compatible.

But I am not able to get full height because it doesn't have that height. By default its `185px` and I am required to have a width of `300px` to show my `swf` file.

Is there any method that can change this box-content class height automatically in JavaScrip or jQuery as recommended by this `p` and `iframe`.

I cannot do directly change the height of this class because it is utilizing on many places.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle? Your question is not so clear.

Comment: Could you add a `min-height: 300px;` to your container?

Comment: ok Brett. Let me use this.

Comment: `p` as container!? You should have `div > iframe`. `p` shouldn't be *used* as block element

Comment: Actually `p` is a block-level element, but i agree it shouldn't be used as a container http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: yes its works. Thanks Brett

Comment: But if somebody want to change parent class values what is the way to do that ?

Comment: @JEES - p comes automatically because i am using opencart framework customer content module. using this i am inserting this iframe. I don't want to change their functionality. So i can't follow something like you have mentioned.

Comment: @EmmaMiller if you want to change or add the parent css this is an example http://jsfiddle.net/7b1k01ma/

Comment: I have a question though, she said "*I need to make this code mobile compatible*" then she said `to show my swf` , mobile browsers still don't run swf files right?

Comment: @EmmaMiller What do you mean by "if somebody want to change parent class values" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

As Brett suggested, and if you for what ever reason can't change the html, this css rule will do the trick:

```
.box-content p {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

**But**, below sample shows how it could/should look like.

I also moved the inline styles to css rules, which make it easier to later change the behavior, and the most appropiate tag as a container would be a `div`, not a `p`.

```css
.swf-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.swf-container iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-content">
    <div class="swf-container">
        <iframe src="http://localhost/imagebase/image/data/banner/swf/Comp1.swf"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```